# .find() Is finding values elements that are not apart of the search criteria

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am using `.find()` on the following json object, which I've named records:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "61f9da9fcc6888f201f722cb",
    "firstName": "joe",
    "lastName": "jergen",
    "email": "joe@outlook.com",
    "status": "active",
    "amount": "5600"
  }
]
```

I then try to find a user in my object using find():

`let userProfile = records.find((x) => (x.email = "peter@google.com"));`

When I log userProfile it seems to pull joe@outlook.com still even though the user is not in the object. The desired behaviour would be null/undefined

Comment: Assignment vs comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to do `x.email === "peter@google.com"`

`=` is an assignment operator while `===` is a comparison operator.

Comment: Why is this downvoted ? this answers the question clearly. the OP is not aware of Assignment vs comparison operations.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping made a typo while trying to answer fast, but fixed it quickly lol